# What is "[+]" in xemacs regular expression?

Tags: regex, gdb, xemacs

In (my) XEmacs 21.4,  describe-variable for gdb-prompt-pattern gives:

```
Value: "^>\\|^(.*gdb[+]?) *\\|^---Type <return> to.*--- *"
```

What is the "[+]" in there?  Does it just mean "the + character"?  If so, why not use "\+"?

Answer (score 3):

In your context, `[+]`  is the same as `\+`, that is matching the `+` character, and I imagine the original writer of that regexp either did so for readability reasons, or perhaps because  `[+]` used to be in the past some set of chars like  `[-+]`

Answer (score 1):

in regular expression `[+]` is symbol `+`

any symbol in `[]` is symbol except `-`

Comment: Not exactly the regexp `[0-9]` should match any digit, not the set of three char `0` or `-`  or `9`, and `[^0-9]` should match any non-digit char.